# How to start automatic redirect after clicking a button in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with the code

```
setTimeout(function(){
location.replace(location.search.substr(1));
}, 5000);
```

I used it in an HTML page where it redirects example.com/re.html?www.google.com to www.google.com. Now I wondering how to change the code that, after I clicked a button (i.e., manually start the redirect), the above code should start work.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: Just wrap the code in a function and set it as the button's `onclick`.

Comment: Why not just make a link? It's what they're for, and they don't need JavaScript. `<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to google.com</a>`.

Comment: The code works on the basis of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011782/how-can-i-create-an-leaving-site-interstitial-page-for-an-existing-site-with-tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap your existing code in a function and add a button with a click event handler which calls that function. Something like below (I commented out the actual redirect code for the exmaple, but you can see how it works):

```js
function redirect() {
  console.log('redirect(...);');
  /*setTimeout(function() {
    location.replace(location.search.substr(1));
  }, 5000);*/
}

document.getElementById('btnRedirect').addEventListener('click', redirect);
```

```html
<button id="btnRedirect">Redirect</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you helpful this

```
 <html>
    <body>
       <button id="mybtn" type="button"> Rederet to Example.com </button>
       <script>
          document.getElementById("mybtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
               window.location.assign("https://www.example.com")
          }); 
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```